# When does quartz Scheduler JobListener.jobWasExecuted() method get called?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am working on our server jobs that are scheduled with Quartz. Currently we are trying to find a way to notify the user when a job is finished. I was trying to use the JobListener.jobWasExecuted() method but it seems to be called now when the job finishes executing, but after the execute method is called (and before it returns).

Is this correct behavior or am I doing something wrong?

If there are any other suggestions on how I can make this happen that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
After looking at it more, it looks like the listener is operating correctly (jobWasExecuted() is getting called once the execute method returns) for all but the first instance of the job. We have several instances of the same job running concurrently. Is there any reason why that would be?

Answer (score 1):

Another way for this is to check whether the job is running currently or not. You can use the method below to identify whether your job is running or not in your job class.

```
private boolean isJobRunning(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws SchedulerException
{
    List<JobExecutionContext> jobs = ctx.getScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

    for (JobExecutionContext job : jobs)
    {
        // check if the current job is already running (make sure to check that fire times are different so that a different
        // instance of the same job is checked)
        if (job.getJobDetail().getJobClass().getName().equals(this.getClass().getName()) && !job.getFireTime().equals(ctx.getFireTime()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Copy pasted from the link : http://wordgraphs.com/post/607/Checking-if-a-Quartz-job-is-already-running

Comment: This answer would be a good workaround if I can't figure out why the first job listener isn't working correctly. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit similar problem. Which was actually being raised due to the duplication of name attribute of the job listener; which should be unique.

jobWasExecuted() method of listener gets called after the execute method of the job has finished its work. Roughly the Call hierarchy is like this

1. Listener->jobToBeExecuted()
2. Job->execute()
3. Listener->jobWasExecuted()

PS: Though a bit late but may be helpful to someone.:D

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was starting a job that wasn't part of the group I was using. That caused some weird behavior. Once I removed the line that started the extra job, everything started working as expected